# query to count reverse manytomany field

Tags: python, django

In my application there are users and users can block each other. I want to save each action taken by a user. In an action, a user could perform multiple ban operations on other users. That is why the Action table has a user_list. Now I want to find the total number that other users target the specific user. For example User_5 was targeted by other users 8 times.

```
models.py

class BanMode(models.Model):
    ban_mode = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, null=False)

class CustomUser(models.Model):
    custom_name = models.CharField(max_length=96, blank=False, null=False)
    custom_id = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    
class Action(models.Model):
    taken_by = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)
    ban_mode = models.ForeignKey(BanMode, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=False, null=False)
    user_list = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, blank=False, null=False, related_name="user_list")
```

Following code **successfully** finds the total number of actions on the user performed by other users (users not unique).

```
CustomUser.objects.annotate(banned_by_count=Count('user_list', distinct=False))
```

However, I want to apply a filter. I want to find the total number of actions (for example actions whose ban_mode is 1) on the user performed by other users (users not unique). This query does not work.

```
CustomUser.objects.annotate(banned_by_count=Count('user_list', distinct=False, filter=Q(action__ban_mode__ban_mode="BAN")))
```

Comment: Are there `related_name`s in the fields of the `Action` model? Normally this can not work without specifying any `related_name`s...

Comment: yes you are right, it has related field same with its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You filter with:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

CustomUser.objects.annotate(
    banned_by_count=Count(
        'user_list', distinct=False, filter=Q(user_list__ban_mode__ban_mode='BAN')
    )
)
```

otherwise you will filter where the user was the one taking the action, not the "victim".

Comment: It works, thank you. But I don't understand the expression user_list__ban_mode. It is clear that user_list has no ban mode field.

Comment: @h_enes_simsek: it has, we here query in reverse, and you used `related_name='user_list', so that is a way to access the `Action` for a given `CustomUser`, but the main question might be whether `user_list` is a good `related_name=...`, since it is thus the name to access `Action`(s) out of a `CustomUser`.